# Считывание динамических данных | Триггер на каждый аккаунт аля "Прочел \ Не прочел" | Проектирование

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть новости (Например), которые админы добавляют в базу данных.
Есть пользователи, у которых есть окошко, где эти новости высвечиваются.
Как спроектировать БД и все остальное таким образом, чтобы не получилось овер много данных, то есть, если на каждый аккаунт ставить ид новости и триггер, тогда будет n-Аккаунтов*m-Новостей.
ID_Acc | ID_news | Trigger
Что очень много.

Comment: Это крайний случай - если __все__ аккаунты прочтут __все__ новости. Но такого никогда не будет. А если и будет то в тестовом режиме с десятью аккаунтами и ста новостями, и 1000 строк для таблицы - семечки.

Comment: У каждой новости есть штамп времени. У последнего вывода новостей клиенту есть штамп времени. Сравнить их - дело плёвое...